# Two servers using same name servers?

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it possible/recommended for two servers to use the same name servers?

For example, if I have two VPS servers; one for business one for personal. Can they both use the same name servers?

Comment: If all my servers had to use different unique nameservers, I'd be a little bit screwed.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to be more clear?  If you're asking "Can two computers use the same DNS server?" the answer is "Yes, just like two computers can both connect to the same web server.", but I don't that's what you're trying to ask :)

Comment: @Tom - imagine the environmental damage if it was a 1-DNS-server-to-1-client ratio - the world would look like something from the matrix

Comment: @Chopper3 - We'd all just revert back to downloading and using THE hosts file.

Comment: @Answerers: Nice gravatars, guys.  Bunch o' Chopper slappies!

Comment: @squillman - I was just about to comment on that myself.

Comment: @ChrisMuench: Did these clowns actually answer your question?

Comment: Yes, my question has been answered, I am still a little unsure how to set it up

Comment: @ChrisM The name server or setting up your servers to point to the name server? Sounds like a new question

Comment: whats wrong with you guys? why are you using the same avatars?

Comment: @NARKOZ: I've got no idea what you're talking about; they're different.

Comment: see this; http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1850/paddington-bear-choppertar

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If they can both see the name servers in question (i.e., not on an internal network to one of them)...sure.

Comment: This would be the major consideration - also many ISP's DNS servers these days only answer recursive requests from "authorized" clients (machines on a network they were set up to serve) to avoid DNS cache poisoning attacks and ungrateful bandwidth/resource moochers using the service for free.

Answer (score 25):

A large proportion of the internet uses the Google name servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 so yes.

Comment: Delicious google name servers

Answer (score 20):

Yes - this is how the internet works.

Answer (score 18):

Indeed, name servers are hearty things that can handle one, two or even three concurrent connections at a time. I think you're safe in using one name server for both VPSs.

Answer (score 17):

Certainly!

If each server needed a server of its own, you'd end up with a horrific sort of pyramid scheme  where the servers at the bottom wouldn't have any servers to call upon.

---

Edit: fixed avatar

[image: MikeyB]

Comment: If you provide DNS service to 5 friends, and they provide DNS service to 5 of their friends…

Comment: Downvoted for inappropriate avatar. Succumb to the hivemind and you'll live.

Comment: Conformity is sooooo much better, don't you think?

Comment: I like that avatar! Have an upvote...

Answer (score 14):

Yes, this is the way it is designed to work, otherwise there would be as many name servers as there were sites.

Answer (score 13):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with having more than one client performing lookups against the same server. Just make sure the DNS server is adequately sized to support the load.

Answer (score 13):

There isn't a problem with doing that, it'll work fine.

Answer (score 12):

Yep. This is how "normal" networks are setup.

Answer (score 11):

YES!

A whole bunch of my servers all use the same nameservers.

Answer (score 6):

Two independent name servers seems to be considered sufficient variety. How many computers use the same two name servers seems to be of little consequence. As long as you have two independent sources in different physical whereabouts and dependent on different networks you can attach about as many "clients" as you like. In fact half the world seems to be able to use the same two name servers, there is no reason two servers couldn't :)

Comment: Where's your Choptar?

Comment: Don't tempt the Coppertar minions. We know bear-fu.

Answer (score 6):

You can surely setup your name-servers in one server and use the same for the other using the cpanel inbuilt DNS Cluster feature( WHM >> Cluster/Remote Access >> Configure Cluster). But, It is better if you,

1. Configure nameservers as,

   ns1/ns2.yourdomain.com --> server 1

   ns3/ns4.yourdomain.com --> server 2
2. Cluster the DNS using the DNS Cluster option in your WHM.
3. Use these four nameservers for your domains at your registrar.

By this way, if one of your nameserver server fails, the other will successfully serve for DNS requests(ofcourse there is no use, if the whole server is going to fail, unless you have proper mechanisms configured to handle such instances in place).

DNS Clustering Doc: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/ConfigureCluster

Cheers